# Reloading vs. restarting uWSGI to activate code changes

Tags: python, uwsgi, systemd

After reading the uWSGI's [documentation on reloading](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/articles/TheArtOfGracefulReloading.html#workers-reloading-in-lazy-apps-mode), my understanding was that, for an app that uses `lazy-apps`, writing `w` to uWSGI's master FIFO should trigger a restart of all workers (and hence activate changes in the Python code).

However, that doesn't seem to work for me. I need to restart the `systemd` service (`systemctl restart myservice`) for code changes to take effect. Am I misunderstanding the documentation, or is there an issue with my setup?

My `myservice.service` file looks like this:

```
...
ExecStart=/usr/lib/myservice/virtualenv/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/myservice/uwsgi.ini
ExecReload=/bin/echo 'w' > /run/myservice/masterfifo
ExecStop=/bin/kill -INT $MAINPID
...
```

In particular, `systemctl reload myservice` should write `w` to the master FIFO. I can see from the logs in `systemctl status myservice` that the reload was executed, but the responses to HTTP requests tell me that the old code is still active.

My `/etc/myservice/uwsgi.ini` like this:

```
[uwsgi]
processes = 16
procname-master = myservice
master-fifo = /run/myservice/masterfifo
touch-chain-reload
listen = 128

thunder-lock
reload-on-as = 4096
limit-as = 8192
max-requests = 2000

; termination options
vacuum
die-on-term

; application
chdir = /usr/lib/myservice
virtualenv = /usr/lib/myservice/virtualenv
module = myservice.uwsgi
callable = app  
master
need-app
enable-threads
lazy = True
lazy-apps = True

; logging
logto = /var/log/myservice/uwsgi.log
log-maxsize = 5242880
logdate = [%%Y/%%m/%%d %%H:%%M:%%S]
disable-logging

; stats server
stats-server = :8201
memory-report

; unix socket config (nginx->uwsgi)
socket = /run/myservice/myservice.sock
chown-socket = api
chmod-socket = 660
```

I'm running version `2.0.19.1` of uWSGI.

Comment: Does sending it a `c`, instead of `w`, make any difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All I know about uWSGI is that it exists, but I noticed a mistake here:

```
ExecReload=/bin/echo 'w' > /run/myservice/masterfifo
```

The man page [explains the problem](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines):

> This syntax is inspired by shell syntax, but only the meta-characters
> and expansions described in the following paragraphs are understood,
> and the expansion of variables is different. Specifically, redirection
> using "<", "<<", ">", and ">>", pipes using "|", running programs in
> the background using "&", and other elements of shell syntax are not
> supported.

In other words, no redirection is taking place and `echo` will simply receive 3 arguments to print: char `w`, char `>` and the string `/run/myservice/masterfifo`.

Try this instead:

```
ExecReload=/bin/sh -c '/bin/echo w > /run/myservice/masterfifo'
```

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly the issue. After fixing the `ExecReload` setting and calling `systemctl daemon-reload`, `systemctl reload myservice` now works as expected.